# Creating Sub Calendars

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

On our University sharepoint site we have a department calendar where dates for the entire department are put. I would like to create a sub calendar that for just events that appears in the main calendar. It would also be useful if the events calendar could be turned on and off by individuals so they can choose to view it or not. I notice next to the department calendar there is a link labelled 'calendars in view' which would lead me to believe sub calendars are possible. Any help I could get with creating these sub calendars would be greatly appreciated.

Jonathan

Answer (score 2):

They aren't "sub calendars" as such, but multiple calendars that are then "layered". So effectively, they are separate lists that are accessed via the one 'view'.

See these guides for setting up multiple calendars, and then layering them.

**First off - create your calendars:**

https://blog.virtosoftware.com/how-to-create-calendar-in-sharepoint/ orhttps://sharepoint.rackspace.com/sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-a-calendar-and-add-an-event

**Then create a calendar overlay:** https://sharepoint.rackspace.com/sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-a-calendar-overlay or https://blog.virtosoftware.com/how-to-overlay-sharepoint-calendars/ or https://sharepointmaven.com/roll-calendars-sharepoint/

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can create multiple overlays in the same calendar list if you create views that filter on a field like "Category". Since each overlay is just a list view, you would set the default view to show nothing (otherwise, each event will appear twice) and then add successive overlays for each individual category.